# replace words in R data.frames (Text Mining)

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, gsub

I'm working on a Text Mining Solution with SQL and R.

First I Import Data into R from my SQL selection and than I do data mining stuff with it.

Here is what I got:

```
rawData = sqlQuery(dwhConnect,sqlString) 
a = data.frame(rawData$ENNOTE_NEU)
```

If I do a

```
a[[1]][1:3]
```

you see the structure:

```
[1] lorem ipsum li ld ee wö wo di dd
[2] la kdin di da dogs chicken
[3] kd good i need some help
```

Now I want to do some data cleaning with my own dictionary.
An Example would be to replace **li** with **lorem ipsum**  and **kd** as well as **kdin** with **kunde**

My Problem is how to do that for the whole Data Frame.

```
 for(i in 1:(nrow(a)))
    {
        a[[1]][i]=gsub( " kd | kdin " , " kunde " ,a[[1]][i])
        a[[1]][i]=gsub( " li " , " lorem ipsum " ,a[[1]][i])
...
    }
```

works but is slow for a lot of data.

Is there a better way to do that?

---

cheers The Captain

Comment: Might be an option to try: do this in SQL directly or calling SQL commands from R?

Comment: SQL and gsub ideas are good so far.  You could also write a custom function in Rcpp if speed is crucial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gsub` is vectorised, so you don't need the loop.

```
a[[1]] <- gsub( " kd | kdin " , " kunde " , a[[1]])
```

is quicker.

---

Also, are you sure you want spaces inside your regexes?  That way you won't match words at the start or end of lines.

Comment: +1 for a clean vectorized solution.  You can use `apply( a, 2, function(x) gsub("kd|kdin","kunde",x) )` if you want to do it for more than one column.

Comment: Thank you. `apply( a, 2, function(x) gsub("kd|kdin","kunde",x) )` did the trick. The spaces in the regexpressions are necessary because otherwise something like **makd** would be translated into **makunde** . I have a huge corpus to handle so problems would be enourmous.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach: avoid regexes altogether.  This works best when you have a lot of different words to search, because you'll avoid the text manipulation except for the first time.

```
a1 <- c("lorem ipsum li ld ee wö wo di dd","la kdin di da dogs chicken","kd good i need some help")
x <- strsplit(a1, " ",fixed=TRUE) # fixed option avoids regexes which will  be slower

replfxn <- function(vec,word.in,word.out) {
  vec[vec %in% word.in] <- word.out
  vec
}

word.in <- "kdin"
word.out <- "kunde"

replfxn(x[[2]],word.in,word.out)

lapply(x,replfxn,word.in=word.in,word.out=word.out)
[[1]]
[1] "lorem" "ipsum" "li"    "ld"    "ee"    "wö"    "wo"    "di"    "dd"   

[[2]]
[1] "la"      "kunde"   "di"      "da"      "dogs"    "chicken"

[[3]]
[1] "kd"   "good" "i"    "need" "some" "help"
```

For a large number of words to search over, I'd guess this is faster than regexes.  It's also more amenable to data-code separation, since it lends itself to writing a merge or similar function to read in the dictionary from a file rather than embedding it in code.

If you really need it  back in the original format (as a space-separated character vector), you can apply a `paste` to the result.

And here are timing results.  I stand corrected: looks like gsub is faster!

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  gsub( word.in , word.out , a1) ,
  lapply(x,replfxn,word.in=word.in,word.out=word.out) ,
  times = 1000
  )

                                                        expr    min     lq
1                                gsub(word.in, word.out, a1)  42772  44484
2 lapply(x, replfxn, word.in = word.in, word.out = word.out) 102653 106075
  median       uq    max
1  47905  48761.0 691193
2 109496 111635.5 970065
```

Comment: you are right about that. I experimented with lapply and had the same experiences. It turned out that my loop was so time consuming.