# Replacing strings in R

Tags: r, apply, gsub, lapply

I am trying to replace strings in R in a large number of texts.

Essentially, this reproduces the format of the data from which I try to delete the '\n' parts.

```
document <- as.list(c("This is \\na try-out", "And it \\nfails"))
```

I can do this with a loop and gsub but it takes forever. I looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845443/replace-words-in-r-data-frames-text-mining/6848796#6848796) for a solution. So I tried: `temp <- apply(document, 2, function(x) gsub("\\n", " ", fixed=TRUE))`. I also used lapply, but it also gives an error message. I can't figure this out, help!

Comment: not sure whats wrong with just `gsub("\\n", " ", document, fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: I forgot to add some useful information here. The gsub("\\n", " ", document, fixed = TRUE) solution destroys the formatting of the list. I need the two lines to appear as two different lines of a list.

Comment: See answer below if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

use `lapply` if you want to return a list

```
document <- as.list(c("This is \\na try-out", "And it \\nfails"))
temp <- lapply(document, function(x) gsub("\\n", " ", x, fixed=TRUE))
##[[1]]
##[1] "This is  a try-out"

##[[2]]
##[1] "And it  fails"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both suggestions were very helpful, it seemed my initial attempt with lapply missed the ", x", part.

Comment: @user3604060, if this answer you question, please select it as one. Thank you. Also, you used `apply` not `lapply`